# Special conditions for finding classes within if-statements?

Tags: php

Let's jump right in to some contextual code. Please read the following...

(1) This works fine:

```
new myClass();

class myClass{
    // Stuff
}
```

(2) Doesn't work (fatal error class not found):

```
if ($_POST['apikey'] == "foo") {
    new myClass();

    class myClass{
        // Stuff
    }
}
```

(3) Solution to above:

```
if ($_POST['apikey'] == "foo") {        
    class myClass{
        // Stuff
    }

    new myClass();
}
```

Can't really find why I needed to do what I did to fix it. I know it's a scripting language, but why would (1) work? Is it some kind of quality of life feature in php that doesn't work once I start nesting it in if-statements or similar?

Comment: Conditionally creating classes and functions is a bad practice and going to cause huge debug headaches.

Comment: You should put your classes in their own files and load them using an autoloader (lazy loading = they won't be included unless you use them). Then they can be reused as well, which your current solution won't allow.

Comment: Your class definition is conditional, and defined ___after___ you try to use it; conditionally defined classes generally aren't a good idea, and class files with an autoloader is a lot more efficient

Answer (score 7, accepted):

PHP compiles and parses the script before it runs.  So it knows about definitions before it starts execution of the script.

This would be blocked if you have a conditional definition because the compiler can't possibly know what that condition will equate to until the script is executed.

In my opinion, you should never define a class, function, or constant inside a condition.  That is what variables are for.

Comment: In some cases this is may be acceptable. For example, for code generation, or for other special things. But _only if you know exactly how it works_.